# Hibernate with more than one dataBase

Tags: java, hibernate

I need to use hibernate with 2 or more bases. Since these bases have the same table, I imagine that there will be no problem when using the same objects paras tables that repeat. So being, I wonder how to spend other files on HibernateUtil establishing the connection, using different files hibernate.cfg.xml, but with the same mapping properties.

I imagine it's something along these lines:

```
   sessionFactory = new AnnotationConfiguration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
```

but i dont have idea how to configure a other file.

Comment: Are you talking about a single application using two databases? Or deploying an application to either use one database or another? If the former, why is the application using two databases? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Exactly what @Hedley said... for the second(choose a database on the fly) multiTenancy in Hibernate might cover your needs

Comment: I have 15 million records in 2 years, and I think I share these data to improve search.

Answer (score 0):

The thing is to have 2 different session factory providers, each one configured with its corresponding data base.

In the example below `HibernateUtilDb1` will use the configuration in `hibernate-db1.cfg.xml`, and `HibernateUtilDb2` will use `hibernate-db2.cfg.xml`.

```
public class HibernateUtilDb1 {

    private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory = buildSessionFactory();

    private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() {
        try {
            return new Configuration().configure("hibernate-db1.cfg.xml").buildSessionFactory();
        }
        catch (Throwable ex) { ...}
    }
...
```

And:

```
public class HibernateUtilDb2 {

    private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory = buildSessionFactory();

    private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() {
        try {
            return new Configuration().configure("hibernate-db2.cfg.xml").buildSessionFactory();
        }
        catch (Throwable ex) { ...}
    }
...
```